# Is there any good way to determine if an object is a clone of another?

Tags: c++, clone

Using the equality operator comes to mind, but you need to define it, which means updating it every time a new data member is added to that class.  And this needs to be done for all classes that are being checked.  Any other good way?

Comment: Cast both to `void*`, then to `char*` and compare?

Answer (score 4):

There is a reason you need an equality operator for anything that is complex enough to manage its own resources. There is no **good** way of automatic comparison. Bitwise comparison works fine for POD types, but nothing else. Any pointer member will possibly point to different addresses even though the object might appear to be logically a clone<sup>1</sup>. Furthermore, the Standard is not very specific about the memory layouts of classes, so even with the lack of pointers and virtual functions it might fail (or at least it's probably UB).

---

<sup>1. I'd argue that comparison is a fundamentally logical operation for complex objects. POD types just happen to be bitwise comparable because they are equal iff they are bitwise equal.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There are many operations that want a tie.

In C++14 it is easy to get one.

```
struct foo {
  template<class Self> // may have template and friend reversed
  friend auto make_tie(Self&&self){
    return std::tie(self.a,self.b,self.c);
  }
  // ...
```

with a `make_tie`, `<` `==` `hash` `swap` `print` (and probably others, like `serialize`, except serialize needs versioning) can all be written once, and apply to many types.

You do have to maintain `make_tie` for this to work.  Reflection working group in the C++1z track are working on additions to the language that may make `make_tie` require less maintenance.

But at least you get many operations (some useful) out of one extra list of member variables.

It helps if your pointers are smart  --  if your pointers are value-semantics, `==` should compare values, and if shared, `==` should compare identity, if unique, `==` should do either.  Non-default cloning operations will require non-default `==`: push the non-default copy into resource management classes and put the `==` logic there.

Answer (score 0):

There is always C's [`memcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp) function:

```
memcmp(&obj1, &obj2, sizeof(obj1));
```

Where `obj1` and `obj2` are of the same type

Comment: Only valid for packed plain old data, which is basically never.  I can stick garbage in the space between member fields of a clone, and probably will if I construct a clone in memory that is not pristine.